# How to create my an installer for my DLL?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, windows-installer

I am currently using Visual C++ to develop my DLL program. This DLL also uses outside executables inside my local hard drive.

When doing testing, I manually install the DLL using this command `regsvr32 filename.dll` at the Windows command prompt.

What I would like to do now is an installer, like the Installshield etc. So, after this I can easily install it on other Windows machines without the need to manually use the command prompt, copying those separates executables into the hard drive and so on.

Is there a way to do this the open source way? or Is it available inside Visual Studio? Need advice on best practice.

Comment: Some setup authoring tools have an auto-register option for files. This registers the required files on the target machines. If you choose a tool which doesn't have such options, you can register the DLL through a custom action. This custom action can  launch regsvr32.exe with the required command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility since you're already using VS, you can create a "Setup and deployment project", found under "Other Project Types". This allows you amongst other things to select the output of another VS project (in the same solution), add registry entries, package files from the file system, and register (regsvr32) files. To register a DLL (once you have added it to the project), change the "Register" entry on the "Properties" Window to vsdrfCOMSelfReg. However if you're packaging other executables off the hard drive, I'm not sure how you would make sure that they run. You prob have to make sure that you package all their run-times and dependencies.

AFAIR this functionality is not available in the express editions of VS.

Comment: Hi, my executables are stand alone. How can I package it together with my DLL installer?

Answer (score 2):

[WiX](http://wix.codeplex.com/) is open source, and there's a free (no cost) version of [InstallShield](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/company/newscenter/pressreleases/press-releases_11119.htm) available for Visual Studio 2010, so both.